# Get Windows Screen Scale in WinForms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a custom draw method in a WinForms application that breaks when the user changes their screen scaling. They can do this by:

```
Right Click on Desktop > Click Personalise > Display > Select 125%.
```

How do I get access to the resolution scale so that I can recalculate the size of my controls for this increased screen scale?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `Control.AutoScaleFactor`.  I haven't tested it with other scaling factors, but if your scale is set to 100%, `Control.AutoScaleFactor.Height` and `.Width` return 1 (i.e. "100%").

Comment: `AutoScaleFactor` is (1, 1) regardless of DPI setting. (IE: even on a workstation that has 200% Font scaling, it is still (1, 1)).